# Pyspark - print messages from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I set up a kafka system with a producer and a consumer, streaming as messages the lines of a json file.

Using pyspark, I need to analyze the data for the different streaming windows. To do so, I need to have a look at the data as they are streamed by pyspark... How can I do it?

To run the code I used [Yannael's Docker](https://github.com/Yannael/kafka-sparkstreaming-cassandra) container. Here is my python code:

```
# Add dependencies and load modules
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--conf spark.ui.port=4040 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.0,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3 pyspark-shell'

from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from random import randint
from time import sleep

# Load modules and start SparkContext  
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("Streaming test") \
    .setMaster("local[2]") \
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

try:
    sc.stop()
except:
    pass    

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# Create streaming task
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 0.60)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "127.0.0.1:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {'test': 1})
ssc.start()
```

Comment: [`DStream.pprint`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html?highlight=pprint#pyspark.streaming.DStream.pprint)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either call `kafkaStream.pprint()`, or learn more [about structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) and you can print like so

```
query = kafkaStream \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I see that you have [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra)endpoints, so assuming you're writing into Cassandra, you can use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/cassandra.html) rather than writing Spark code for this

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007! As a first test, I included `kafkaStream.pprint()` and as a result I got the current time... Do you have any suggestion on how to have the proper messages?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "proper"

Comment: Shouldn't I see as output the messages in the `test1` topic? As far as I understand, I subscribed to it in `kafkaStream`

Comment: Yes, you should, but only as they are actively being produced into the topic. By default, it consumes from the latest offsets